# How to change first name in shipping address on this page using event observer magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, shipping-methods

Please explain with examples and provide the code of execute method if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one code

> IZANOVA\StackExchange\etc\events.xml

```
 <event name="sales_order_save_before" >
       <observer name="sales_order" instance="IZANOVA\StackExchange\Observer\SalesOrder"/>
 </event>
```

> IZANOVA\StackExchange\Observer\SalesOrder.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace IZANOVA\StackExchange\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrder implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()
            ->setCustomerFirstname('test')
            ->setCustomerLastname('test')
            ->setCustomerEmail('test@gmail.com');
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: where did this event trigger? It is not triggering on the checkout page.

Comment: its trigger when you press place order button

Comment: But I want to event for checkout page as mentioned in my question. refer screenshot posted by me.